# $L^{p}$ spaces and their properties

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I have  a question: I don't know how to show

that if  $1<p<q<\infty$ , then $L^{q}(0,1)\subset L^{p}(0,1)$ and
$\mid\mid f\mid\mid_p$ < $\mid\mid f\mid\mid_q$, $\,f \in L^{q}(0,1)$?

Comment: Do you know Hölder's inequality?

Comment: ... or Jensen's inequality?

Answer (score 2):

If $1<p<q<\infty$, and $f\in L^q(0,1)$, then
$$
\int_0^1 \lvert\, f(x)\rvert^p\,dx=\int_0^1 \lvert\, f(x)\rvert^p\cdot 1\,dx
\le \left(\int_0^1\lvert\, f(x)\rvert^q\,dx\right)^{p/q}\left(\int_0^1 1^r\,dx\right)^r=
\left(\int_0^1\lvert\, f(x)\rvert^q\,dx\right)^{p/q},
$$
where
$$
\frac{p}{q}+\frac{1}{r}=1\quad\text{or}\quad r=\frac{q}{q-p}.
$$
Hence
$$
\left(\int_0^1 \lvert\, f(x)\rvert^p\,dx\right)^{1/p}=\|\,f\|_p\le \|\,f\|_q
= \left(\int_0^1 \lvert\, f(x)\rvert^q\,dx\right)^{1/q}.
$$
Therefore, if $f\in L^q(0,1)$, then $\int_0^1\lvert\,f(x)\rvert^p\le \left(\int_0^1\lvert\, f(x)\rvert^q\,dx\right)^{p/q}<\infty$, and hence $f\in L^p(0,1)$. Therefore, 
$$
L^q(0,1)\subset L^p(0,1).
$$

Comment: thank you,and how I can show that $L^{q}$(0,1)$\subset$$L^{p}$(0,1)?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** apply the Holder inequality with the parameters $\frac qp > 1$ and $$
\frac{\frac qp}{1-\frac qp}
$$